# Implementing gravity into simple 2D ball throwing simulator

Tags: math, 2d, gravity

I'm creating a simple simulator for basic throwing of spherical objects (which I've cleverly termed *balls*). When the user clicks on the screen, the ball will begin travelling in that direction at a speed of (distance from ball to mouse). The ball will be affected by gravity, and therefore travel in a parabola.

The original plan was to implement this as follows (pseudo-code, with dynamic tickrate correction removed for clarity):

```
on click:
    ball.forwardTheta = atan2(mouseY - ball.y, mouseY - ball.x)
    ball.speed = sqrt((mouseX - ball.x)^2 + (mouseY - ball.y)^2) / 50

tick:
    ball.x += ball.speed * cos(ball.forwardTheta),
    ball.y += ball.speed * sin(ball.forwardTheta);
    ball.forwardTheta += Math.PI / constGravity;
```

This results in a system that works similar to how I'd like, however, I'm worried about this causing further issues down the line, such as once I try to implement the balls bouncing at an angle of reflection, etc., as currently most times a ball collides with a surface at an angle of *Pi/2* (straight down), meaning there is no angle of reflection.
After some research, it appears a common simple implementation of gravity is by subtracting a constant value of gravity from a moving object's y coordinate every tick, however this doesn't seem proper to me but more of a cheat, so my question is the "proper" way to go about implementing gravity for parabolic movement of objects in 2D space.

Answer (score 2):

Gravity makes an acceleration, so speed (not coordinates explicitly) changes every tick.

In general case

```
ball.speed.x = ball.speed.x + acceleration.x * timequant
ball.speed.y = ball.speed.y + acceleration.y * timequant
```

For case of y-directed gravity

```
ball.speed.y = ball.speed.y + g * timequant
```

and x component of velocity does not change

Not that component-wise representation of speed would help you in reflection calculation (for example, reflection from vertical border negates x-component)